# Dropdown not getting selected using Selenium Webdriver on Safari browser 10 in Mac

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

On Safari browser I need to select an Option from the dropdown.
below code works for all the browsers except for Safari on Mac OS. I am using Safari 10.1.1 with selenium web driver version 3.3.1  I have written the code in Java. Refer the code below -

```
webElement = findElement(field);
if (webElement.isDisplayed())
{
  Select select = new Select(webElement);
  select.selectByVisibleText(value);
}
```

Comment: are you getting any err message?

Comment: No, I did not receive any error message.

Comment: Can you give me the DOM?

Comment: I am facing this issue in Safari browser only.                                                     and unable to maximize the Safari window

Comment: I am not able to guess the issue... Can you give me more details like site you are trying with so that i can try with my mac and help?

Comment: Dom details <select id="profileItem_10536" name="value(profileItem_10536)" onchange="change_profileItem_10536()" required="required">
<option id="profileItem_10536_select_one" value="">-- select one --</option>
<option id="profileItem_10536_11703" value="11703">Yes</option>
<option id="profileItem_10536_11704" value="11704">No</option>
<option id="profileItem_10536_12292" value="12292">Already Booked</option>

Comment: site sharing is not possible

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code:

```
public void jsSelect(WebElement element, int index) {
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].selectedIndex=" + index + ";", element);
    }

public void jsSelect(WebElement element, String item) {
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("const textToFind = '" + item + "';" +
            "const dd = arguments[0];" +
            "dd.selectedIndex = [...dd.options].findIndex (option => option.text === textToFind);", element);
}
```

Comment: You could explain what you changed.

Comment: With these methods you can select by index or visible text the value in select-option element using JavaScript, this works for me with safari driver

Answer (score 0):

Can you check, if the below code works in Safari..

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='profileItem_10536']"));
Select sel = new Select(dropdown);
sel.selectByVisibleText("Yes");
```

If the code doesn't work in Safari and works in other browsers let me know...

**Update:**

Everything should work fine on Sierra if you use the correct driver (supplied by Apple). You shouldn't be using Selenium's SafariDriver with Safari 10.

> specifically:
>
> "The old SafariDriver implementation is no longer maintained and
>   should not be used." "Safari now provides native support for the
>   WebDriver API. Starting with Safari 10 on OS X El Capitan and macOS
>   Sierra, Safari comes bundled with a new driver implementation that’s
>   maintained by the Web Developer Experience team at Apple." Also note:
>
> "Safari’s WebDriver support is turned off by default"

It seems apple provided its own safari driver and its available at

> "/usr/bin/safaridriver"

Kindly use this drive. For more details regarding this kindly look into https://webkit.org/blog/6900/webdriver-support-in-safari-10/ and https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3145

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your response.                                                                           above code is working in Chrome browser not working in Safari browser

Comment: Last two days onwards I am facing this issue. before that same code working in Safari browser also.                                                                      i am unable to find out what is the issue

Comment: In this case, can you check updating safari driver

Comment: In Safari >> Preferences>>Extensionlist added webdriver 2.45

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on Java Selenium 3.141.59 when using the default Select that is npt supported by Safari webdriver, tried also with clicks on the Select web element and then on the targeted option...also not working, resolved it by using Javascript to select the desired option and then fire the relevant event in order to simulate the onchange action :

```
public void selectFromDropDownForSafari(final WebDriver driver, final String selectId, final String expectedOption) {
    WebElement selectElement =  driver.findElement(By.id(selectId)); 
    // Get the option tags under the Select element
    List<WebElement> options = selectElement.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
    if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(options)) {
        for(int index = 0; index < options.size(); index++) {
            WebElement option = options.get(index);
            // Search for an option having the same value attribute OR the displayed text (handling both possibilities)
            if(expectedOption.equals(option.getAttribute("value")) || expectedOption.equals(option.getText())) {
                JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                // Select the targeted option by index and launch the onchange event
                executor.executeScript("arguments[0].selectedIndex=" + index + "; arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));", selectElement);
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("No option with the desired value [" + expectedOption + "] was found in the Select element");
    }
    throw new Exception("The Select element does not have any option");
}
```

On my case, this wouldn't work properly without sending the corresponding event by javascript (dispatchEvent)

Answer (score -1):

Select is not working on Sierra 10,12.6  safari 11.0
I tried the below and they do not work as nothing happen and no error shown.

```
selectByIndex(3) 
selectByValue("value"), 
selectByVisibleText("Yes");
```

If you try to use :
Send key method then the select option is populated.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

None of the dropdown select functions work in Safari.
As a workaround I have used element.type("") in Selenium and it worked in place of Select.